# Passing a struct by value to another function initializes it to zero

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a thread library and my thread is a `struct` type. Have to follow a certain interface and in that I need to pass the `thread` by value. For ex: to join on a thread my code is as follows:

```
int thread_join(thread_t thread, void **status1)
{
    printf("Joining thread\n");
    long int thId = thread.id;
    printf("Thread id: %ld\n", thId);
    gtthread_t * thrd = getThreadFromID(thId);
    while(thrd->status != EXIT)
    {

    }   
    status1 = &(thrd->ret_value);
    return 0;
}
```

And I an passing a `struct` of type `thread_t` to this function. My problem is when I see the thread's ID in the calling function, its displayed properly but when I check it in the `thread_join` function its displayed as 0. The caller function is as follows:

```
void* caller(void* arg)
{
    thread_t th;

    thread_create(&th, some_function, NULL);
    thread_join(th, NULL);

    while(1);
}
```

Thread create initializes the ID of the thread to a non-zero value and starts the function associated with it.

My thread structure (and other relevant structure is):

```
typedef enum
{
    RUNNING,
    WAITING,
    CANCEL,
    EXIT
} stat;

//Thread
typedef struct 
{
    ucontext_t t_ctxt;
    long int id;
    stat status;
    void  * ret_value;
    int isMain;
} thread_t;


int thread_create(thread_t *thread, void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg)
{
    thread = (thread_t *)malloc(sizeof(thread_t));
    thread->id = ++count;
    thread->status = RUNNING;
    thread->ret_value = NULL;
    thread->isMain = 0;
    if(getcontext(&(thread->t_ctxt)) == -1)
        handle_error("getcontext");
    thread->t_ctxt.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(SIGSTKSZ);
    thread->t_ctxt.uc_stack.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    thread->t_ctxt.uc_link = &sched_ctxt;
    makecontext(&thread->t_ctxt, (void (*)(void))wrap_func, 2, (void (*)(void))start_routine, arg); 
    enqueue(gQ, thread);
    printf("Thread id: %ld\n", thread->id);
    swapcontext(&(curr_thread->t_ctxt),&sched_ctxt);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen? After all, I am passing by value and this should create a copy of the `thread` with the same values. Thanks.

EDIT:

Basically I am having a queue of threads and there is a scheduler which round-robins. I can post that code here too but I'm sure that's needless and that code works fine.

EDIT2:

I am making a header file from this code and including that header in another file to test it. All my `thread_t` variables are static. The caller is a function which includes my header file.

Comment: Can you show the caller

Comment: Show us the carfax (the rest of the code that is relevant).

Comment: carfax? Not heard that before

Comment: @Rob lol, just feeling like being random today but still wanting to help people out on here :P

Comment: Can you also show the definition of `thread_t`? I know `pthread_t`, not this one.

Comment: Could you also post the thread_create function?

Comment: That would make this question unnecessarily big. But I'll do it anyways.

Comment: Where do you get count from?

Comment: OT: Shouldn't this `status1 = &(thrd->ret_value);` be `*status1 = thrd->ret_value;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is this line:

```
thread = (thread_t *)malloc(sizeof(thread_t));
```

for?

You pass in to `thread_create()` an address which referrs to a `struct thread_t` defined in `caller()` as `auto` variable.

Doing as you do, you allocate memory to the pointer passed in to `thread_create()` initialise it and forget the address on return.

The code never writes to the memory being referenced by the address passed in! Besides this it is a memory leak.

To fix this simply remove the line of code quoted above.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a bunch! You are a life-saver! But don't I have to initialize any references that I am using by using malloc?

Comment: @TheRookierLearner: `thread` as received by `thrrea_create()` is a valid address already initialised to the memory which is `auto`-allocated in `caller()` by defining `thread_t thread` prior to calling `thread_create()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have no mutex guard on thread id getter. Presumably, there is no guard on setter. What *can* be happening is that the variable is not visible in the other thread yet. And, without a critical section, it may never become visible.

Each variable which is accessed for both read and write from different threads has to be accessed in a critical section (pthread_mutex_lock / unlock).

Another possibility is that you are setting the thread id inside the running thread and you are accessing the variable even before it is set. If you attempt to join immediately after starting a thread it is possible, that the other thread hasn't been run at all yet and the variable is not set.

side note: do yourself a favor and use `calloc`:)

Answer (score 1):

In caller function,

`thread_create(&th, some_function, NULL);`

should be

`gtthread_create(&th, some_function, NULL);`

Comment: My bad. That's not the problem (or I would get an error for uninitialized function)